# Chamar um ajax dentro do sucess de outro ajax contido no primeiro ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

No clique de um botão classe `cantor` é retornado o nome do cantor e botões com classe `musica` com seus respectivos nomes das musicas `(data)`. Ao clicar em um botão classe `musica` é retornado a letra da musica `(data2)`, nesse ponto gostaria de adicionar um botão para acionar o primeiro ajax `(classe cantor)` para relacionar o cantor e suas respectivas musicas novamente. Fiz uma tentativa como se pode ver nos comentários do script abaixo, porém não funciona. Existe alguma forma de realizar essa operação?

```
$('.cantor').click(function() {
 
    $th = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        url: "pagina1.php",
        type: 'GET',
        data: {cantor: $th.attr( "title" )},
        success: function(data){
            $("#resultados").html(data);

                        $('.musica').click(function() {
                          $thm = $(this);
                          $.ajax({
                            url: "pagina2.php",
                            type: 'GET',
                            data: {identificador: $thm.attr( "title" )},
                            success: function(data2){
                            
                            
                                /*########### tentativa coloquei um button class cantor - não funciona ###### */
                                $("#resultados").html('<button class="cantor" title="Fulano de Tal">Fulano de Tal</button>'+data2);
                                
                                
                                
                            },
                            error: function(){
                                $("#resultados").html("Ouve um erro ao enviar sua URL");
                            }
                         });//ajax 
                    });

            
        },
        error: function(){
            $("#resultados").html("Ouve um erro ao enviar sua URL");
        }
     });//ajax 
});
```

Comment: A solução passa pelo friend @Barmar neste post   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727230/calling-an-ajax-within-the-success-of-another-ajax/65727449#65727449

Answer (score 1):

Seria isso?

```js
$('.musica').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $thm = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "pagina2.php",
        type: 'GET',
        data: { identificador: $thm.attr("title") },
        success: function (data2) {

            /*########### tentativa coloquei um button class cantor - não funciona ###### */
            $("#resultados").html('<button class="cantor" title="Fulano de Tal">Fulano de Tal</button>' + data2);

        },
        error: function () {
            $("#resultados").html("Ouve um erro ao enviar sua URL");
        }
    });//ajax 
});

$('.cantor').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "pagina1.php",
        type: 'GET',
        data: { cantor: $th.attr("title") },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#resultados").html(data);

            // Chama o evento de clique
            $('.musica').trigger('click');


        },
        error: function () {
            $("#resultados").html("Ouve um erro ao enviar sua URL");
        }
    });//ajax 
});
```

Comment: Não está voltando para as musicas por causa dessa linha.
**<a href="https://musicasitalianas.com/index-m.php"><img border="0" src="https://musicasitalianas.com/images/back.gif"></a>**
essa tag a esta fazendo um redirect para a pagina, ai ela recarrega os valores iniciais.